# UserManager.Create does not generate identity after migration to 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, .net-core-3.0

After I have migrated to asp.net core 3.0 UserManager.Create does not generate identity value for the column Id of the table users, I am using asp.net identity and I use this code to the change the table name

```
 builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
```

and this to create the user

```
 var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Comment: What made you expect an identity column would be created?

Comment: sorry my bad, I mean it does not generate a value for the identity column Id.